# I trying to figure out in how many film categories is the average difference between the film replacement cost and the rental rate larger than 15

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to figure out in how many film categories is the average difference between the film replacement cost and the
rental rate larger than 15. but i keep doing something wrong.
Categories is found under film_list table and (film replacement and rental_rate) are from film table

```
SELECT categories,avg(replacement_cost) as Average, -(select avg(Rental_rate) from film) as Difference FROM film,film_list  WHERE  Rental_rate > 17;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the average based on categories, you need to use a group by. Otherwise, it will do the average of everything in all categories.

You could try:

```
Select
     categories,
     AVG(replacement_cost)-AVG(Rental_rate) as Difference
From film
Group By categories
Having AVG(replacement_cost)-AVG(Rental_rate) >15
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't work because Categories is found under film_list table and (film replacement and rental_rate) are from film table.

Comment: Is there a table that has categories? If so, you can join it with the film_list table.